# Convert bytes to list of 2s complement 8 bytes signed integer

Tags: python, list, memory, integer

`python 3.7`

Having a `bytes` of a size multiple to `8` is there a way to convert to a `list` of 8 bytes large signed integers? I tried the following:

```
some_bytes = #retrieve bytes
print(list(some_bytes)) #prints as it was treated a 4 bytes integers
```

Is there a way to convert `bytes` to list of 8 bytes signed integers?

Comment: The result you describe is impossible from the input you describe; a `bytes` object is an iterable of individual byte values, so converting to `list` would result in 1-byte values, not 8-byte values. Please read [mre] and make sure the question is properly specified and that you really do have `bytes` input.

Comment: I didn't take `The question as asked` because if I did I wouldn't answer half the questions I see on SO, OP is obviously not the best at English, so I had to interpret his question. `bytes` can be converted to a list of signed integers, which is OP's question, and so I answered that.

Comment: *"prints as it was treated a 4 bytes integers"* - That's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `bytes()`

```py
import struct

message = 'Python is fun!!!'

# convert string to bytes
byte_message = bytes(message, 'utf-8')
print(byte_message)

num_integers = len(byte_message) // 8
print(num_integers)

integers = struct.unpack(f'{num_integers}q', byte_message)
print(integers)
```

### Python 3.9+

```py
from random import randbytes
import struct

THIS_MANY_INTEGERS = 4
random_bytes = randbytes(8*THIS_MANY_INTEGERS)

num_integers = len(random_bytes) // 8
integers = struct.unpack(f'{num_integers}q', random_bytes)
print(integers)
```

If you don't have `randbytes`

```
import random
import struct

byte_size = 8  # Number of bytes per signed integer
number_of_integers = 5 # To create a valid length bytearray just for this example code

data = bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for _ in range(8*number_of_integers))
num_integers = len(data) // byte_size
# same as number_of_integers, use this if you don't know the length of the bytearray and check the length is correct, otherwise you'll get "struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of N bytes"
integers = struct.unpack(f'{num_integers}q', data)
print(integers)
```

## Python `struct` Module

The `struct` module in Python is used for packing and unpacking binary data. It enables the conversion between Python data types and binary representations.

Important for your question are:

- `struct.pack(format, v1, v2, ...)`: Packs values into a binary string based on the specified format.
- `struct.unpack(format, data)`: Unpacks binary data into Python values using the provided format.

`q` is for [long long](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#:%7E:text=(2)-,q,(2),-Q)

Read about [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) and [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) to better understand what's going on

Comment: The question as asked has nothing to do with actually getting the input; it's assumed that said input already exists. Therefore there is no point in showing the extra code to generate random data, and especially not in showing version-specific ways of doing so - that's answering a question that wasn't asked and isn't related.

Comment: It's important to know that he can´t just throw any amount of bytes and expect it to work. He says he has `bytes` of a length multiple of 8 so, sure, he doesn't need the explanation, but this answer is not just for him, many other people might reach here and who knows what they know, what they have in their code and what version of python they use. So I provided code that can run independently of their own code. If I had to take `The question as asked` I wouldn't answer half the questions I see on SO, OP is obviously not the best at English, so I had to interpret his question.

Comment: "If I had to take The question as asked I wouldn't answer half the questions I see on SO," - if everyone followed that advice, the site would be much better off. Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**, and that the primary purpose of questions is to serve as a *searchable reference*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`struct.iter_unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack) with a format of [`'q'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), which denotes a signed 8-byte integer. Since `iter_unpack` yields a sequence of tuples, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to join the integers inside the tuples into one sequence before converting them to a list:

```
import struct
from itertools import chain

print(list(chain.from_iterable(struct.iter_unpack('q', some_bytes))))
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzbCsMgEETf8xW@aaGE3C//shDUGCJN1JoNbL/eNm3nbeYcJrxw9a4eQkzJ7sFHZAfGU2O2RL8ziyai99vB/lCv0rosC9E6FJs9UHyX/LKny5ZqM@J3kV99Ol2Q@iH4k9@Z4kBFCVTVQE0L1PVAwwgkFZCegcwCtBigWQMpCTQOQH0H1DZAdQVUFvz2SUpv)